# How do I count distinctly in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I need to have a query count the number of records and put the count beside the record it represents. Example:

```
Turkey
France
Turkey
United States
Italy
Italy
Turkey
France
United States
France
Italy
Italy
```

Turns into:

```
Country       NumberOfVisits
Turkey           4
France           3
United States    2
Italy            4
```

I can't seem to get the countries to show on their own line in this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use a `Group By` in your SQL Statement, E.g.:

```
SELECT Country, Count(*) as NumberOfVisits FROM CountryTable GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: Sweet. I was putting the GROUP BY clause before my FROM clause. Thanks!